# php unpack binary string without format

Tags: php, binary, pack, unpack

Is there any way to unpack a binary string without knowing the format which it has been packed with?

I'm having a binary string transmitted to my server via UDP. The problem is that the documentation regarding the packing has been lost and cannot find the supplier of the device that is sending this string in order to request it again.

Comment: A binary string can be pretty much anything and no tool will automatically (and reliably) decode it for you. Could you elaborate on what data you are receiving?

Comment: no way, you can suppose it any type